# Overriding Lifestyle when Registering a Collection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I have configuration where I need to register two controllers that are simply:

```
public class DataApiController : ApiController
{
    readonly Data _data;
    readonly MongoRepo _mongoRepo;
    readonly JobManager _jobManager;
    readonly QueueManager _queueManager;

    public DataApiController(QueueManager queueManager, 
        MongoRepo mongoRepo, JobManager jobManager, Data data)
    {
        _queueManager = queueManager;
        _mongoRepo = mongoRepo;
        _jobManager = jobManager;
        _data = data;
    }

    ...           
}
```

and another that also uses `ApiController`. I need to register them as a collection, which I'm doing thusly:

```
var types = new[] { typeof(DataApiController), typeof(BatchApiController) };
container.RegisterCollection<ApiController>(
    from type in types
    select Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration(type, container));
```

While that works I get errors that the Transient setup needed is in error due to `IDisposable`. OK, I get that and I see that there's an example for getting around that when registering a single item:

```
public static void RegisterDisposableTransient<TService, TImplementation>(
    this Container container)
    where TImplementation : class, IDisposable, TService
    where TService : class
{
    var scoped = Lifestyle.Scoped;
    var reg = Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration<TService, TImplementation>(container);
    reg.SuppressDiagnosticWarning(DiagnosticType.DisposableTransientComponent,
    "suppressed.");
    container.AddRegistration(typeof(TService), reg);
    container.RegisterInitializer<TImplementation>(
        o => scoped.RegisterForDisposal(container, o));
}
```

Is there no override for the error suppression for a collection? I can't get anything to work that suppress the diagnostic warnings, it's like that's just being ignored when the container is verified and I always get the error/warning about Transient and `IDisposable`. How can I register a collection and let the container know that I get it and I need to suppress the error?  Registering a single API Controller with the `RegisterDisposableTransient` above works fine, but I need to use the collection due to two implementations on one service.

Comment: How do you resolve a collection of controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the following and everything should work fine:

```
container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

container.RegisterCollection<ApiController>(new[] {
    typeof(DataApiController), typeof(BatchApiController)
});
```

The reason this will work is because:

- `RegisterWebApiControllers` will register all the application's controllers with the `Transient` lifestyle (by their concrete type) and will add a suppression to that registration.
- Simple Injector will forward any (concrete) types registered using `RegisterCollection` back to the container, and it will reuse any existing registration.

This results in the existing registrations for `DataApiController` and `BatchApiController` (registered using `RegisterWebApiControllers`) to be reused, including their suppressions.

In case those two ApiControllers aren't registered using `RegisterWebApiControllers` (perhaps because they are in a different assembly), the following will do the trick as well:

```
var r1 = Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration<DataApiController>(container);
r1.SuppressDiagnosticWarning(DiagnosticType.DisposableTransientComponent, 
    "done by web api");

container.AddRegistration(typeof(DataApiController), r1);

var r2 = Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration<BatchApiController>(container);
r2.SuppressDiagnosticWarning(DiagnosticType.DisposableTransientComponent, 
    "done by web api");

container.AddRegistration(typeof(BatchApiController), r2);

container.RegisterCollection<ApiController>(new[] {
    typeof(DataApiController), typeof(BatchApiController)
});
```

Comment: What solved this for me (after too many hours of trying) was in fact the order that I was registering everything.  I was building the container and adding the registrations, including collections, and then registering the WebApi controllers.  I get the notion that registering will do its thing, but man that was in no way intuitive.  Thank you.